# Why can you assign an array to a char pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, string-literals

Usually when you declare a pointer (such as an int) you'd have to assign a memory address to it:

```
int value = 123;
int* p = &value;
```

When you create a char pointer, you can assign a char array to it without the need of including an address:

```
char* c = "Char Array";
```

How does this work? Does it allocate memory and point to that? Why can't other type pointers do the same thing?

Comment: You can't do this for instance: `char* c = &'a';`

Comment: Notice that `char *c = "char array"` won't compile in C++; did you want to ask about C, instead?

Comment: @Daniel Your C++ compiler sucks if it doesn't at least give you a warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How does this work?

The string literal is stored in a read-only data section in the executable file (meaning it is initialized during compilation) and `c` is initialized to point to that memory location. The implicit [array-to-pointer conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/3425536) handles the rest.

Note that the conversion of string literals to `char*` is deprecated because the contents are read-only anyway; prefer `const char*` when pointing to string literals.

A related construct, `char c[] = "Char Array";`, would copy the contents of the string literal to the `char` array at runtime.

> Why can't other type pointers do the same thing?

This is a special case for string literals, for convenience, inherited from C.

Answer (score 1):

Other type pointers can do this as well just fine. A string literal is array of chars, so you don't need to use address operator to assign to pointer.

If you have an integer array, either int * or int[] you can assign it to int pointer without using the address operator as well:

```
int intArray1[] = {0, 1, 2}; // fist array
int * intArray2 = new int[10]; // second array
// can assign without & operator
int * p1 = intArray1;
int * p2 = intArray2;
```

The `char *` is just specific that the string literal type is actually `const char *` and is is still allowed to assign (with a warning about deprecated conversion).